# What should I do for resolving java.util.NoSsuchWElementExceptionn runtime error for java.util.Scanner class?

Tags: java, java-17

I have this runtime error: Error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException     at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)   at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)   at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)   at ArrayOperations.main(Main.java:31)

what should I repair in this code? :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ArrayOperations {
    public static void reverseElements(int[][] twoDimArray) {
        // write your code here
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {
            int left = 0;
            int right = twoDimArray[i].length - 1;

            while (left < right) {
                int temp = twoDimArray[i][left];
                twoDimArray[i][left] = twoDimArray[i][right];
                twoDimArray[i][right] = temp;

                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] twoDimArray = new int[3][4];

        // System.out.println("Enter the elements of the twoDimArray:");

        for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < twoDimArray[i].length; j++) {
                twoDimArray[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }

        reverseElements(twoDimArray);

        // System.out.println("Reversed twoDimArray:");

        for (int[] row : twoDimArray) {
            for (int element : row) {
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

I want resolve this runtime error because I have workout  on Hyperskill. Program work correctly in my IntelliJ input and output are correctl but after checking IntelliJ with Hyperskill website show me this error.
Thank you for your help and answer .
input is this:

```
0 0 9 9 
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
```

output is this:

```
9 9 0 0
4 3 2 1
8 7 6 5
```

Comment: What is the input which you provide when running in IntelliJ? What is the input in the web platform which is given to the program? And what this question has to do with gradle (You tagged it with "gradle"?

Comment: input and output is this:    0 0 9 9     change to                  9 9 0 0 under this number is 
                                            1 2 3 4      change to                  4 3 2 1 under this is
                                            5 6 7 8      change to                 8 7 6 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters change your code like that and run it on the online platform:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < twoDimArray[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Reading element for index [" + i + "][" + j + "]");
            String debug = scanner.next();
            // twoDimArray[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Read element for index [" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + debug);
        }
    }
```

Let us know what is the output.